# Can WPF KeyBinding Key have several alternative values?

Tags: wpf

I have a `KeyBinding` with the `Key` set to <kbd>D1</kbd> which is the `1` key.  This isn't the same as <kbd>NumPad1</kbd> key.

Is there a way to have something like:

```
Key="D1 && NumPad1"
```

So that pressing either <kbd>D1</kbd> or <kbd>NumPad1</kbd> would execute the command?

I've added a second KeyBinding one for each key D1 & NumPad1, but that seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the answer - but what can I do, I'm just a programmer.  :)

Comment: Yes you can :) ___________

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can - **comma delimited**  :-)

I am not certain if in the question you want to use two KeyBindings to signify that user would have to push the key twice. But that's what I was looking for. If that's the reason then this post will work.

For example, I wanted to use + to go forward, and ++ to double-go-forward, and - to go-back, -- to go double back in my app:

```
<KeyBinding Key="OemMinus"  Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding GoBack}"/>
<KeyBinding Key="OemMinus,OemMinus" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding GoBack2X}"/>
```

The reason I figured it out, was that I know that in VisualStudio you have a ton of commands that have double key, like commenting, or collapsing regions. And you know that VS2010's written in WPF. So I looked on the VS menu, and there are ton of commands comma separated: 
View > Solution Navigator Cntr + W, F. 
I tried it and it worked!

Comment: Any idea how to do this in codebehind and not XAML?

Comment: I tried this, but all that happens is that my equivalent of GoBack is called twice, am I missing something?

Comment: This does not work , in Visual studio Ctrl+ W, F is equivalent to Ctrl+W , Ctrl + F , where as the code provided in the answer will simply set the last value of the Comma Delimited as the actual shortcut. For example, if the above code defined Key="K,OemPlus" then that shortcut is simple equivalent to Key="OemPlus"  , the reason being is that Key is an Enumeration that accepts only a single value.